# Package theme in magento go

Tags: theme, magento-go

I have installed a theme for my Magento go store and added some my own customizations to it, now is it possible that I can have whole theme packaged as one, so I can use it as it base theme for my other  projects/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not.  Magento Go themes and extensions are in a *closed* marketplace.  You need to be a member of their [trusted extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/trusted_extension/) program to package things for Magento Go.

Comment: @AnshuMishra If you found this (or any) answer helpful could you upvote it?  We're trying to get out of beta here :)

Comment: Can you please help me by giving some explanation on http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6443/different-methods-for-creating-blocks