# Different methods for creating Blocks

Tags: blocks

What is the difference between below two pieces of code?

Code 1

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('CLASS_GROUP_NAME/PATH_TO_BLOCK_FILE')->toHtml();
$this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
```

Code 2

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('PATH/RELATIVE/TO/TEMPLATE/*.phtml')->toHtml();
$this->getResponse()->setBody($block);
```

Comment: Looks like an error to me? I don't think setTemplate should have a class, it should have a file name ending with .phtml

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, I have changed that to some path to phtml file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Splitting this apart

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('PATH/RELATIVE/TO/TEMPLATE/*.phtml')->toHtml();
```

This

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template');
```

instantiates a `Mage_Core_Block_Template` object.  The class name comes from looking in the merged `config.xml` for a node inside `<blocks/>` named `<core/>`, and then appending the word `Template`.

then this

```
$block->setTemplate('PATH/RELATIVE/TO/TEMPLATE/*.phtml');
```

Will set a variable named `template` on the `Mage_Core_Block_Template` object.

then this

```
$block->toHtml();
```

will render the block as HTML.  It just so happens a `Mage_Core_Block_Template` block's `toHtml` method renders the block by loading a `phtml` template set in the template variable.

Then, splitting apart this

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('CLASS_GROUP_NAME/PATH_TO_BLOCK_FILE')->toHtml();
```

This

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('CLASS_GROUP_NAME/PATH_TO_BLOCK_FILE');
```

instantiates a block object.  It gets the base class name from looking in the configuration for a node named `<class_group_name/>` under the `<blocks/>` configuration node. (for this example, let's say that's `Packagename_Modulename_Block`) — and then appending `PATH_TO_BLOCK_FILE` to the end of this.  This is the same process as with `core/template` above.  This gives us a block named `Packagename_Modulename_Block_Path_To_Block_File`.

Then this

```
$block->toHtml();
```

calls the `Packagename_Modulename_Block_Path_To_Block_File`'s object's `toHtml` method, which renders the block.  It maybe `Packagename_Modulename_Block_Path_To_Block_File` extends from `Mage_Core_Block_Template`, and has had it's template set inside itself, or it may be a block that contains different logic for rendering in `toHtml`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, This is really very good and helpful for me.

Comment: "*The class name comes from looking in the merged  config.xml*"
Where is this file?

Comment: @Black Every module has a config.xml.  Magento merges these with PHP code, and stores the merged tree in its cache.  There is no file that represents a merged XML tree.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite the same method. The difference are :

CASE 1 This call uses a specific block, with its own method and feature (i.e load collection, set caching, etc.). It may have a default template set so you don't need to specify it.

CASE 2 This call uses the default frontend block, YOU NEED to define the template to use. You only have default block feature in this one (see the mentionned class to find more info).